# Shiny App - Loading csv with column names from Input Text

Tags: r, csv, import, shiny

I am trying to load csv file with columns names from Input text, if header = FALSE. The textInput in col.names(c() works bit weird. When i entered textInput as "a","b","x" the input text is read as "\"a\",\"b\",\"x\"".

```
library(shiny)
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  colm <- renderText({input$cols})
  head <- renderText({input$header})

contents <- reactive({ 

    infile <- input$file1
    if (head() =="TRUE") {        
    if (is.null(input$file1)) {return(NULL)}
    read.csv(infile$datapath)}
  else  
    {  
      if (is.null(input$file1)) {return(NULL)}

      read.csv(infile$datapath, header = input$header,sep=",",col.names=c(str(input$cols)))
  }})
  output$data <- renderTable({contents()})
  output$man <- renderText({colm()})
  output$men <- renderText({head()})

})

UI.R

library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("The Ace!"),
           navbarPage("Calulus@Work",  
            tabPanel("About Tool",p("The tool designed for single place for Analytics.")),
            navbarMenu("Data Load",
            tabPanel("Delimter",
            sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                                               accept = c('text/csv',
                                                 'text/comma-separated-values',
                                                 'text/tab-separated-values',
                                                 'text/plain','.csv','.tsv'
                                               )),
                                     tags$hr(),
                                     checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                                     textInput('cols',"Enter column names"),
                                     radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',
                                                    Tab='\t'),','),
                                     radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                                  c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
                                     tags$hr(),
                                     ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                     tableOutput('contents')

textOutput("man"),
                                     textOutput("men")
                                   ))),
                        )                  
                         )#navbarPage

)#fluidpage
)#shinyUI

Error:
chr "\"a\",\"b\",\"x\""
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Kindly help on this issue

Comment: I doubt this is a Shiny issue. Just test it in straight R.

Comment: its working in R...please see code used below..                                                   var <- c("scrip","trading_day","Open","close","High","Low","Volume")
nasdaq <- read.csv("E://sqream//sample data//test.csv",header=FALSE,as.is=TRUE,col.names=c(var))